# Android Tablet Application Development Query

Tags: android, tablet

I am an ANDROID app developer,
i just need to know, that what are the conditions and things ,to create app for android tablets.

Is there any registration fees apart from the $25, where should i register and how to develop, is it different from android mobile app development.

Plz suggest.

Regards

Comment: NO its not that much different from android mobile app. Just some screen size/resolution and/or any extra h\w functionality can be differ. You can get the emulator to develop tab app.

Comment: so i just change my emulator screen resolution to 1024 by 768 and i am done with Table app ???

Comment: Yes, if you do not care your app would look crappy on tablets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there are no significant changes as of yet. However, the 3.0 SDK will add several new features we haven't used before as well as hardware acceleration. sweet! :) good luck!

Comment: Thanks,one more thing, where should i upload tablet app?At the same place, where we upload android mobile app? how it gonna be different from from mobile app? thanks again

Comment: I actually don't know for sure, but I guess it all comes down to how you tag and specify your app. If you are making a "tablet only-app" i think you should make it very clear to the potential downloaders. Oh, and the Market is the same for both tablets and phones... :)